Difference in the event loop execution for es6 and common js modules
Why is it that the below code gives output differently for es6 modules and common js modules:
process.nextTick(() => console.log("nextTick 1"));
process.nextTick(() => {
    console.log("nextTick 2");
    process.nextTick(() => {
        console.log("inner tick inside nexttick");
    });
});
process.nextTick(() => console.log("nextTick 3"));

Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("Promise 1"));
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log("Promise 2")
    process.nextTick(() => { 
        console.log("tick inside the Promise");
    });
});
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("Promise 3"));

In commonjs, it seems more in accordance to the event loop, that is nextTicks CBs are run before the promise CBs. But in ES6 module, why all promise CBs are run first, and then the nextTick CBs are run?
